# Prolog Rules/Queries

Tags: prolog, rules

Given the following facts:

```
people(ana, az, 13).

people(sam, ca, 24).

people(tom, il, 5).

people(ginger, ca, 52).
```

How would I write a prolog rule that answers the following question?

> Person is the adult if he is greater than 17 years of age?

This is what I have so far.... (Thanks in advance I'm new at this)

```
is_adult(Person):-
    people(Person, State, Age).
    Age>17.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably taken the altitude from some other example, right?

This how it should look like

```
is_adult(Person):-
    people(Person, State, Age),
    Age>17.
```

Comment: Yup :) but never mind I figured it out. I exchanged the "." for ",". A careless mistake on my part- should have been: people(Person, State, Age),  Thank you anyway.

Comment: Good that you've figured it out. If you like my answer you can accept it ;-)